# AWS Glue - Truncate destination postgres table prior to insert

Tags: python, postgresql, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to truncate a postgres destination table prior to insert, and in general, trying to fire external functions utilizing the connections already created in GLUE.

Has anyone been able to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overwrite MySQL tables with AWS Glue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556678/overwrite-mysql-tables-with-aws-glue)

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I also want to do something like this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've tried the `DROP/ TRUNCATE` scenario, but have not been able to do it with connections already created in Glue, but with a pure Python PostgreSQL driver, [pg8000](https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000).

1. Download the tar of [pg8000 from pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pg8000/#files)
2. Create an empty `__init__.py` in the root folder
3. Zip up the contents & upload to S3
4. Reference the zip file in the `Python lib path` of the job
5. Set the DB connection details as job params (make sure to prepend all key names with `--`). Tick the "Server-side encryption" box.

Then you can simply create a connection and execute SQL.

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job

import pg8000

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, [
    'JOB_NAME',
    'PW',
    'HOST',
    'USER',
    'DB'
])
# ...
# Create Spark & Glue context

job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# ...
config_port = 5432
conn = pg8000.connect(
    database=args['DB'], 
    user=args['USER'], 
    password=args['PW'],
    host=args['HOST'],
    port=config_port
)
query = "TRUNCATE TABLE {0};".format(".".join([schema, table]))
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Actually , I did the exact steps as you mentioned, but still I am getting "No module named pg8000". Can you help me where I went wrong. P.S I got lib from https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000

Comment: I'm also getting the same error - No module named pg8000. how did you overcome this? is there anything else need to be added?

Comment: While this is good, does this guarantee transaction? Assume there is a data frame write statement after the connection, will the table still be truncated if there is some error while writing the data frame to DB? @thenaturalist

Comment: To use the `pg8000` module with a Glue job is now simpler. Go to 'Security configuration, script libraries, and job parameters (optional)', scroll down to 'Job Parameters' and enter `--additional-python-modules` for the key and `pg8000` for the value.. and you're done :)

Answer (score 2):

```
data=spark.sql(sql)
conf = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf("jdbc-commerce")
data.write \
    .mode('overwrite') \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", conf['url']) \
    .option("database", 'Pacvue_Commerce') \
    .option("dbtable", "dbo.glue_1") \
    .option("user", conf['user']) \
    .option('truncate','true') \
    .option("password", conf['password']) \
    .save()
```

glue api not support , but spark api support.

jdbc-commerce is your connection name at crawl.
use extract_jdbc_conf to get url、username and password.

Comment: For this to work, I had to add `.option("connschema", "<database>")` to the options.

Answer (score 1):

After following step (4) of @thenaturalist's response,

`sc.addPyFile("/home/glue/downloads/python/pg8000.zip")`

`import pg8000`

worked for me in a development endpoint (zeppelin notebook)

More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html

Answer (score 1):

To clarify @thenaturalist instructions for the zip as I still struggled with this

---

Download the tar.gz of [pg8000](https://pypi.org/project/pg8000/#files) from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/) and extract.
Zip the contents so you have the below structure

```
pg8000-1.15.3.zip
|
| -- pg8000 <dir>
    | -- __init__.py
    | -- _version.py <optional>
    | -- core.py
```

Upload to s3 and then you should be able to just do a simple `import pg8000`.

> NOTE: [scramp](https://pypi.org/project/scramp/#files) is also required at the moment so follow the same procedure as above to include the scramp module. But you don't need to import it.