# Overwrite MySQL tables with AWS Glue

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a lambda process which occasionally polls an API for recent data. This data has unique keys, and I'd like to use Glue to update the table in MySQL. Is there an option to overwrite data using this key? (Similar to Spark's mode=overwrite). If not - might I be able to truncate the table in Glue before inserting all new data?

Thanks

Comment: I am wondering the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workaround I've come up with, which is a little simpler than the alternative posted, is the following:

- Create a staging table in mysql, and load your new data into this table.
- Run the command: `REPLACE INTO myTable SELECT * FROM myStagingTable;`
- Truncate the staging table

This can be done with:

```
import sys from awsglue.transforms
import * from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("URL", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("REPLACE INTO myTable SELECT * FROM myStagingTable")
cursor.fetchall()

db.close()
job.commit()
```

Comment: How do you do that within a Glue Job?

Comment: I am curious why are you are replacing the target DB from a temporary table instead of just `DELETE FROM target_table` and then run the rest of the Glue job?

Comment: @AlexMarkov `DELETE FROM` would require iterating through all of the records in glue, correct? Where as the operations above are all batch. Also, there is some (albeit very small) amount of time when there would be 'missing' records (which, in our case, is important not to have).

Comment: @JoeC, I tried using pymysql library in my glue job and it failed due to external library issue.  The AWS Support says we need to use pymysql as a zip file and use it as a dependant jar file.  Is that true, or if not can you please help how to use / reference pymysql jar ? This is working in development end point, but when running as a Job, it is failing. Shoud this be added as a dependant jar or reference jar? Tx

Answer (score 8):

I found a simpler way working with JDBC connections in Glue. The way the Glue team recommends to truncate a table is via following sample code when you're writing data to your Redshift cluster:

```
datasink5 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
                frame = resolvechoice4, 
                catalog_connection = "<connection-name>", 
                connection_options = {
                          "dbtable": "<target-table>", 
                          "database": "testdb", 
                          "preactions":"TRUNCATE TABLE <table-name>"}, 
                redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], 
                transformation_ctx = "datasink5"
            )
```

where

```
connection-name your Glue connection name to your Redshift Cluster
target-table    the table you're loading the data in 
testdb          name of the database 
table-name      name of the table to truncate (ideally the table you're loading into)
```

Comment: It will not work if you will migrate the data from redshift to MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue with Redshift, and the best solution we could come up with was to create a Java class that loads the MySQL driver and issues a truncate table:

```
package com.my.glue.utils.mysql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MySQLTruncateClient {
    public void truncate(String tableName, String url) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        try (Connection mysqlConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement statement = mysqlConnection.createStatement()) {
            statement.execute(String.format("TRUNCATE TABLE %s", tableName));
        }
    }
}
```

Upload that JAR to S3 along with your MySQL Jar dependency and make your job dependent on those. In your PySpark script, you can load your truncate method with:

```
java_import(glue_context._jvm, "com.my.glue.utils.mysql.MySQLTruncateClient")
truncate_client = glue_context._jvm.MySQLTruncateClient()
truncate_client.truncate('my_table', 'jdbc:mysql://...')
```

Comment: Thanks for the work-around :)
I feel like they should have this solved

Comment: Thanks for the work-around, this helped us connect to SQL Server for running queries before and after the load into the table from Glue.

Comment: @Raman I did the same for SQL Server but i am getting an error  TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable