# How to fix "module 'pg8000' has no attribute 'connect'" error in AWS Glue job

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, pg8000

I'm trying to set up a daily AWS Glue job that loads data into a RDS PostgreSQL DB. But I need to truncate my tables before loading data into them, since those jobs work on the whole dataset.

To do this, I'm implementing the solution given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984173/11952393.

It uses the pure Python library pg8000. I followed the guidelines in this SO, downloading the library tar, unpacking it, adding the empty `__init.py__`, zipping the whole think, uploading the zip file to S3 and adding the S3 URL as a Python library in the AWS Glue job config.

When I run the job, the pg8000 module seems to be imported correctly. But then I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pg8000' has no attribute 'connect'
```

I am most certainly doing something wrong... But can't find what. Any constructive feedback is welcome!

Comment: Is it spark or python shell job?

Comment: Sandeep, it is a Python Spark job.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
install_requires = ['pg8000==1.12.5']
```

in `_setup.py` file which is generating `.egg` file

You should able to access library.

Comment: I've edited this answer to remove the bit about doubling percent signs as that bit isn't correct.  import pg8000.dbapi

c = pg8000.dbapi.connect("postgres")
cursor = c.cursor()
cursor.execute("select 'hello' like '%ell%';")
for r in cursor.fetchall():
    print(r)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what made it work for me.

1. Do a pip install of the pg8000 package in a separate location

   `pip install -t /tmp/ pg8000`
2. You would see 2 directories in the /tmp directory

   ```
   pg8000
   scramp
   ```
3. Zip the above 2 directories separately

   ```
   cd /tmp/
   zip -r pg8000.zip pg8000/
   zip -r scramp.zip scramp/
   ```
4. Upload these 2 zip files in an S3 location
5. While creating the job or the Dev Endpoint mention these 2 zip files in the `Python Library Path` field

```
s3://<bucket>/<prefix>/pg8000.zip,s3://<bucket>/<prefix>/scramp.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error. It turns out that I was assembling the .zip file to be uploaded to AWS incorrectly (at the command prompt on Mac).

I created the .zip file with:

```
zip ../function.zip *
```

which resulted in the directories (such as pg8000, but all the others as well) being included, *but not their contents*.  As such, the error message was true!  There were no attributes, because there wasn't even a `__init__.py` file!

Instead, what should be done is:

```
zip ../function.zip -r *
```

When done correctly, the contents of the directories should browsable within the AWS Lambda Code editor.